How to change the URL of a request using Retrofit and Okhttp (Recreating retrofit2.Call)
I want to change the URL of my request after it fails once. Let me elaborate...
So if I made a call to www.abc.com/whatever and for some reason this call fails, I want to make the subsequent retries to www.abc-2.com/whatever. Now the problem is, I have been using a utility method to wrap my API calls around try-catch and retry logic. It looks something like this:
suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(apiCall: suspend () -> Response<T>): Result<T> {
    val maxRetries = 5
    val retryCount = 0
    while (retryCount < maxRetries) {
        try {
            val response = apiCall.invoke()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                return Result.success(response.body)
            } else {
                retryCount++  
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            // do some logging
            retryCount++  
        }
    }
} 

... and the API service interface looks something like this:
interface MyApiService {
    @GET
    suspend fun getApiData(
        @Url completeUrl: String,
        @QueryMap queries: Map<String, String>,
        @HeaderMap headerMap: Map<String, String> = hashMapOf()
    ): Response<MyApiData>
}

In my repository or ViewModel, I make the API call something like this:
suspend fun getMyApiResponse(): Result<MyApiData> {
    return safeApiCall {
        apiService.getApiData(
            completeUrl = "www.abc.com/whatever",
            queries = listOf(),
        )
    }
}

Now, in safeApiCall method, if the first API call fails, I want to change the host of my api endpoint, but this isn't straight forward since safeApiCall has no information about the request object. I tried changing the methods in my API service to return call objects like this:
interface MyApiService {
    @GET
    fun getApiData(
        @Url completeUrl: String,
        @QueryMap queries: Map<String, String>,
        @HeaderMap headerMap: Map<String, String> = hashMapOf()
    ): Call<MyApiData>
}

but now I have a new problem, while I have access to the request object and the original endpoint to which the request was made, I cannot create a new Call object with the new endpoint to enqueue it since retrofit does that internally, at runtime (AFAIK). Also, it is important to retrieve the origin endpoint since the decision for obtaining the new endpoint depends on the original one.
Is there any method through which I can achieve the URL switching without changing much with safeApiCall method. I know I could've used an Interceptor but then I would have to move all the retry related logic to it and Interceptors just don't seem to the right choice for retrial logic.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

"and Interceptors just don't seem to the right choice for retrial logic" -- why is that?

Yep. Use an interceptor.

@CommonsWare because we are using a bunch of interceptors and I want to execute all the logic inside all of the interceptors when retrying. Interceptor order will come into play. This can be a source of bugs in future.

"we are using a bunch of interceptors" -- perhaps you should be consolidating them. When one of the OkHttp/Retrofit maintainers recommends a solution, ideally you would step back and identify ways to use that recommendation.

@CommonsWare I tried the interceptor approach. I don't think parsing exceptions can be caught inside the interceptors and hence I cannot retry. Also what if some error is thrown between request invocation and my RetryInterceptor? For these reasons as well, I feel I cannot migrate my retry logic to interceptors.

Is there any way through which I could transform okhttp.Call to retrofit.Call manually while trying to change the endpoint url in safeApiCall?

"I don't think parsing exceptions can be caught inside the interceptors and hence I cannot retry" -- usually, "this call fails" refers to a server failure response (e.g., HTTP 500). Your question uses "this call fails" and similar terminology, and so Jesse and I assumed the conventional definition. I agree that a parsing error cannot be handled in an interceptor, but a parsing error being an indication to retry a request on a different URL is bizarre, and I do not have any good ideas off the top of my head of how to try to pull that off. Sorry!
